# JQuery menu links not loading on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use Jquery's menu class to create a nav menu for a website I am writing. For some reason, I cannot get the links to load properly. If I right-click and hit open in new window it works, but not on a direct click.

Here is my HTML code (assuming Jquery and Jquery-ui are imported):

```
$(function() {

    $( "#menu" ).menu({});
});

<ul id="menu" >
    <li>
        <a href="#">Service</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="customHourReport.php">Report Hours</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="eventHistory.php">Event History</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="memberstats.php">Member Stats</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Fundraising</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="./dlfiles/Application.docx">Support Letter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./dlfiles/SampleLetter.docx">Sample Letter</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Bylaws</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="./dlfiles/Constitution2012-2013.docx">Download Bylaws</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <a href="#">Budgets</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>       
    <li>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="changepassword.php">Change your Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="profpic.php">Upload/Change Profile Picture</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks so much!

Comment: You markup works fine if width is set for `.ui-menu`. Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/2dezn/) for it. Can you reproduce your problem in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you are in jquery method `return false` and `event.preventDefault()`;